# Why does upgrading Ruby on Rails project from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1 cause 'routes.rb' and locale file be overwritten?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded my existing Ruby on Rails project from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1, everything seems fine, but I found the routes.rb file and the locale file just be set to default content (it's like when you creating a new project). All of the routing code and locale translations are just gone. The files are still there, but with no content except the default comments. What did I do wrong? What could possibly cause this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: How can we tell what you did wrong if we don't know what you did.

Comment: perhaps more helpfully... please describe your upgrade process.  Did you just change the Gemfile for the new rails version and rebundle? or was there more work involved?

Comment: Did you run `rake rails:update` and accept all the defaults?

Comment: @Dylan Markow, I ran almost every commands that I found about upgrading. So, did you mean if I ran the rake rails:update command, it will overwrite some of my files?

Comment: Hi Sergio and Michael, I was Google searched for the upgrading process, but it seems every site tells a different way, I did try almost every way, finally I got my Rails upgraded to 3.2.1, but the routes and locale files was secretly got overwritten, I have no idea which step I did causes this disaster...

Comment: If you do run `rake rails:update` it will step through each file it's going to replace and ask you if you want to replace it; you might have done something else. Without knowing the exact steps you took, it would be impossible to say exactly why those files got overwritten.

Comment: In my case (4.1.0 -> 4.1.1), it asks to overwrite several files.  So what is the point?  To overwrite the files with default content, and then you put all your needed stuff back into routes, envs, etc so they are as they were before?